# String index out of range: -1 on find method of JPA

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa-2.0, glassfish-3, hsqldb

I am using HSQLDB + Glassfish + JPA + SpringMVC. I have done the JNDI mapping, created connection pool and placed my HSQLDB.jar(2.2.4) in Glassfish lib folder.

I am able to successfully deploy the application. When I access the app using "localhost:8080/site" It throws the following error on find method(Hibernate) as shown below.

Pls help to resolve this.

```
INFO: [ERROR] 12:23:21 Ejb3Configuration - Container is providing a null PersistenceUnitRootUrl: discovery impossible

INFO: [ WARN] 12:23:21 Ejb3Configuration - hibernate.connection.autocommit = false break the EJB3 specification

INFO: PWC1412: WebModule[null] ServletContext.log():Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'mycompany'
INFO: [ WARN] 12:23:24 RuntimeEnvironmentPropertiesConfigurer - Unable to determine runtime environment, using default environment 'development'

INFO: WEB0671: Loading application [com.mycompany_site_war_1.0] at [/site]
INFO: com.mycompany_site_war_1.0 was successfully deployed in 206,384 milliseconds.
WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[mycompany]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet mycompany threw exception
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1952)
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1925)
    at org.*******.core.catalog.dao.ProductDaoImpl.findProductByURI(ProductDaoImpl.java:392)
    at org.*******.core.catalog.service.CatalogServiceImpl.findProductByURI(CatalogServiceImpl.java:268)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
```

Is this is a persistence problem or some other....?

If it is persistence problem what needs to be checked....?

Comment: Looks like a configuration issue

Comment: Please, could you include some of your `org.*******` code?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `ProductDaoImpl.findProductByURI()` directly calls `String.substring()` with an index of `-1`. So you should have a detailed look at your code to check for the root cause of this.